# How many numbers can be formed using parenthesis in the expression $7$/$8$/$9$/$10$/$11$?

Tags: number-theory

> How many numbers can be formed using parenthesis in the expression 
>   $7$/$8$/$9$/$10$/$11$ ?

**MyApproach**

> I have not understood the question.Can anyone guide me how to solve the problem?

Comment: I think the question means for example you have $(7/8)/(9/10/11)=10.694$ while if you use $(7/8)/(9/10)/11$ then you have $0.0883$ instead. The question is asking how many different result are you able to obtain.

Comment: Do the numbers stay in the original order?

Answer (score 4):

By putting parenthesis you are able to change any of the later three "division" sign to a "multiplication" sign so there are $2^3=8$ numbers can be formed.

Comment: how? Can you give exampleor explain in detail ?I have still not understood?

Comment: For example, if you want $7/8*9*10/11$ you use $7/(8/9/(10/11))$

Answer (score 2):

Even if you don’t see the clever solution noted by **cr001**, you can still solve the problem by brute force, and in the process you can confirm that the eight possible values actually are distinct.

There are $C_4=\frac15\binom84=14$ ways to completely parenthesize $4+1=5$ operands separated by a binary operator, where $C_4$ is a [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics). I’ve listed all $14$ of them below, together with their values; expressions whose values duplicate an earlier value are starred.

$$\begin{align*}
&(((7/8)/9)/10)/11=\frac7{8\cdot9\cdot10\cdot11}=0.0008\overline{83}\\
&((7/(8/9))/10)/11=\frac{7\cdot9}{8\cdot10\cdot11}=0.0715\overline{90}\\
&((7/8)/(9/10))/11=\frac{7\cdot10}{8\cdot9\cdot11}=0.08\overline{83}\\
&((7/8)/9)/(10/11)=\frac{7\cdot11}{8\cdot9\cdot10}=0.1069\overline{4}\\
&(7/((8/9)/10))/11=\frac{7\cdot9\cdot10}{8\cdot11}=7.15\overline{90}\\
*&(7/(8/(9/10)))/11=\frac{7\cdot9}{8\cdot10\cdot11}=0.0715\overline{90}\\
&(7/(8/9))/(10/11)=\frac{7\cdot9\cdot11}{8\cdot10}=8.6625\\
&(7/8)((9/10)/11)=\frac{7\cdot10\cdot11}{8\cdot9}=10.69\overline{4}\\
*&(7/8)(9/(10/11))=\frac{7\cdot10}{8\cdot9\cdot11}=0.08\overline{83}\\
&7/(((8/9)/10)/11)=\frac{7\cdot9\cdot10\cdot11}{8}=866.25\\
*&7/((8/(9/10))/11)=\frac{7\cdot9\cdot11}{8\cdot10}=8.6625\\
*&7/((8/9)/(10/11))=\frac{7\cdot9\cdot10}{8\cdot11}=7.15\overline{90}\\
*&7/(8/((9/10)/11))=\frac{7\cdot9}{8\cdot10\cdot11}=0.0715\overline{90}\\
*&7/(8/(9/(10/11)))=\frac{7\cdot9\cdot11}{8\cdot10}=8.6625
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @Winther: Thanks!

Comment: I'd argue that this is slightly more rigorous: in @cr001's approach, it isn't immediately clear that those are the *only* numbers you can get to, whereas here, it is.